# Moving elements between objects using Java

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm trying to remove from object `resultObjectAtt` the children that has F.
However since I'm removing it from the object, `childElem.size()` will change.

So I tried creating a new object and assigning the old object to it:
 `okResultObject = resultObjectAtt;`

But same results, any help?

```
  okResultObject = resultObjectAtt;    
  for (int j = 0; j < childElem.size(); j++) {

    subChildElem = childElem.get(j).getChildren();

        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < subChildElem.size(); j2++) {
            Name = subChildElem.get(j2).getName();
            Value = subChildElem.get(j2).getValue();

            if(Name.equalsIgnoreCase("TYPE")){
                if(Value.equals("F")){
                    okResultObject.getRootElement().getChildren().remove(j);
                    convertDocumentToXmlFile("C:\\test.xml", okResultObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That assignment just creates an alias of resultObjectAtt. If resultObjectAtt is cloneable, then you can use resultObjectAtt.clone() to get a new object. Otherwise you will need to build okResultObject by some other means such as iterating through the nodes of resultObjectAtt and adding the same values to okResultObject.